# Difference between Postcss and styled-components

Tags: postcss, styled-components

Yesterday only i saw the https://www.styled-components.com , I like very much intrested in styles write in Javascript => **CSS in JS**.

I have some queries mentioned list below points

1.What is different between PostCss and Styled components.

2.How to used rem to pixel in styled components.

Thank you